# Send only changed properties to Breeze's SaveChanges() method

Tags: javascript, breeze

When saving changes in Breezejs, since I have entities with lots of fields, I would like to send to the server (to the Breeze SaveChanges() method) not the entire entities, but instead only a subset of the entity, containing just the properties that have changed. I know that this is what the OriginalValuesMap property inside the entities is there for, it's just in order to reduce the network traffic to improve performance (though it may be a very small improvement). On the official [Breezejs' website](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/save-changes) I couldn't find anything about that, nor on the internet. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We deliberately decided not to do this, because we felt that the performance improvement was not worth the additional complexity.  We made this decision based on several considerations.

- It would only be useful for modifications and deletions, additions would still need to carry every field.
- In most applications, save payloads tend to be much smaller than query payloads.
- Standard HTTP compression makes even the largest of these payloads much smaller.

We have been building RIA applications across a range of technologies for a number of years and in our experience optimizing the save payload rarely gives much in the way of overall application performance gains.

But... please feel free to add this request to the Breeze User Voice. As with other, requests if enough of our users think that this is important, then we will do it.

Comment: Thank you to both of you user3380160 and Jay, I agree with Jay that it's not that much of improvement in performance. I would rather skip it, since I think there are much more important issues like many-to-many support (I had already voted it), and also overwriting of entities values (an issue about which I had posted a question on stackoverflow some time ago but never got any answer).

Comment: And if you really disagree, it's easy to replace the dataservice adapter so that it does something different (just make sure you compensate on the server too!). I can think of one case where you might want to intervene: if your entity has some ridiculously big blob in it. But why did you do that to yourself in the first place?

Comment: Exactly for the reason you described Ward, like some fields with ridiculously big amount of data. I'll try this solution anyway, if it doesn't bring much hassle I'll go for it, otherwise it's not terribly important. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

We ran into a similar requirement for a different reason. One section of our app interfaces with a 3rd party API that insists on deltas for puts (putting full entities causes server errors or serious performance issues on their end for whatever reason).

We ended up rolling a new data service adapter to address this, and it was a relatively painless process. We extended directly off of the base AbstractDataServiceAdapter, but you may be able to get away with a custom _prepareSaveBundle on top of whichever concrete data service adapter you happen to be using.

You'd just have to register the custom adapter:

```
ctor = ->
  @name = 'custom_ds'
ctor.prototype = new breeze.AbstractDataServiceAdapter() # or whatever your base is
ctor.prototype._prepareSaveBundle = (saveContext, saveBundle) ->
  # Do whatever your base implementation does, but use helper.unwrapChangedValues
  # instead of helper.unwrapInstance to get at the delta
breeze.config.registerAdapter 'dataService', ctor
```

And then bind your entity manager to a data service that uses it:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance 'dataService', 'custom_ds'
ds = new breeze.DataService
  adapterName: 'custom_ds'
  # plus whatever other properties you need to init
manager = new breeze.EntityManager
  dataService: ds
  # plus whatever other properties you need to init
```

But if you're just doing this to shrink your payloads, it's probably not worth the hassle and added brittleness for all of the reasons that Jay Traband called out.

Comment: Perfect, it works fine. I had to add the following lines:

`var rawEntity = helper.unwrapChangedValues(e, metadataStore);`
                `rawEntity[e.entityType.keyProperties[0].nameOnServer] = e[e.entityType.keyProperties[0].nameOnServer.camelize()]();`

(the second is to include the id of the entity even if it has not changed) and it works. The only thing to be aware of is, for further releases of Breeze I would also have to check if the code in the dataAdapter definition has changed, and if so update my custom adapter.